# Magento translation email - email titles

Tags: email, magento, translation

How do you go about changing the title of emails in a second language store view. Example "New Order" in the New Order confirmation email. csv files are not responding in this case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution.  You can copy the default email templates into a language folder you are wanting to use, and translate them manually.

1. Copy everything in `app/locale/en_US/template` to `app/locale/[YOUR
   LANGUAGE CODE]/template`.

   Change `[YOUR LANGUAGE CODE]` to the Language Code of your
   desired language.  YOu can find a list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Make sure it's in
   the format `en_US`.
2. Modify the email templates in your `app/locale/[YOUR
   LANGUAGE CODE]/template` folder.
3. In Magento, go to `System > Configuration > General`.  At the top left, change your `Current Configuration Scope:` to the store you want translated.
4. Change the `Locale` to the language you translated to.  It must match correct the language code used in your folder namespace.

**NOTE:** When editing the email template files, you'll notice some comments at the top containing variables and such.  You will see something like `<!--@subject Welcome, {{var customer.name}}! @-->`.  Changing this will alter the subject line used by Magento.

Comment: I am following this approach, thanks for the final NOTE. that is what I overlooked. I assumed it was part of javascript variable section.

Comment: I'd like to add that I have to save as document type UTF-8 with BOM, otherwise bad things may happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create custom Transactional Emails which include the translations needed for the store view.

1. Create a new Transaction Email template, in your store's required
   language.  Go to `System > Transactional Emails` and click `Add New
   Template`.  Load in the default template you are trying to
   translate and modify the subject and body of the email.
2. Go to `System > Configuration > Sales Emails`  At the top left of your configuration, change to your desired Store View you want these emails to be assigned to.
3. Change the `New Order Confirmation Template` to the Transaction Email template you created.  Click `Save Config`.
4. Items ordered from that store should now send an email using the translated email you created.

Comment: Great answers. This type of generosity of specialized knowledge is what makes this site so unique and valuable!